# Initializing nested collections with Backbone

Tags: backbone.js, initialization, marionette

I am trying to nest a Collection View into a Model View.

In order to do so, I used Backbone's Marionnette Composite View and [followed that tutorial](http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/02/03/tutorial-nested-views-using-backbone-marionettes-compositeview/)

At the end he initializes the nested collection view like this:

```
MyApp.addInitializer(function(options){
  var heroes = new Heroes(options.heroes);

  // each hero's villains must be a backbone collection
  // we initialize them here
  heroes.each(function(hero){
    var villains = hero.get('villains');
    var villainCollection = new Villains(villains);
    hero.set('villains', villainCollection);
  });

  // edited for brevity

});
```

**How would you go doing the same without using the addInitalizer from Marionette?**

In my project I am fectching data from the server. And when I try doing something like:

```
App.candidatures = new App.Collections.Candidatures;

 App.candidatures.fetch({reset: true}).done(function() {
    App.candidatures.each(function(candidature) {
        var contacts = candidature.get('contacts');
        var contactCollection = new App.Collections.Contacts(contacts);
        candidature.set('contacts', contactCollection);
    });
    new App.Views.App({collection: App.candidatures});


 });
```

I get an "indefined options" coming from the collection:

```
App.Collections.Contacts = Backbone.Collection.extend({
model: App.Models.Contact,

initialize:function(models, options) {
    this.candidature = options.candidature;
},


url:function() {
    return this.candidature.url() + "/contacts";
}
)};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you're creating the `contactCollection`, you're not providing a `candidatures` collections in an `options` object. You do need to modify your contact collection initialization code to something like:

```
initialize:function(models, options) {
    this.candidature = options && options.candidature;
}
```

That way the `candidature` attribute will be set to the provided value (and if not provided, it will be `undefined`).

Then, you still need to provide the info when you're instanciating the collection:

```
App.candidatures.each(function(candidature) {
    var contacts = candidature.get('contacts');
    var contactCollection = new App.Collections.Contacts(contacts, {
        candidature: candidature
    });
    candidature.set('contacts', contactCollection);
});
```

P.S.: I hope you found my blog post useful!

Comment: Hi David! Very nice to get an answer from you here! Your post is really great! I understand candidature.contacts is already set... but I am not able to retrieve the data :( even modifying as per your suggestion The Contact Model

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I think I am getting closer (after 1 week on this!). But now if in the candidature View (first level) i do console.log(this.model.get('contacts')); I am getting empty objects... Maybe some asynchroneous thing I am missing :(

Comment: Yes, this is probably because the data hasn't beenr eturned when you are trying to fetch it. You should see the APi calls in your Firebug console, though (to see your app is working properly). You can refresh the view by adding a listener in the view's initializer (e.g. listen to collection's "change" event. You can also trigger the collection's change event each time contacts get fetched). To see about waiting for asynchronous data, look at http://davidsulc.com/blog/2013/04/01/using-jquery-promises-to-render-backbone-views-after-fetching-data/

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I finally nailed it after including a huge amount of very hugly code. But it is working! Merci Monsieur, j'adore ce que vous faîtes ;)

Comment: Tant mieux! N'oublie pas de valider la réponse si elle a été utile ;-)